# Ajax request dont send $_POST propertly

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, phonegap

Im trying to develop an android app using php, jquery, mysql and phonegap.

Phonegap environment don't let me use php, but I can locate it in to my server and I request data from database with ajax.

I can do simple queries, but when I use a var taken from `$_POST`, it doesn't works, exactly way `isset($_POST['any_var']) returns false`, but if I do `isset($_POST) returns true`, so I think I have an incorrect `dataString`.

I'm new in this kind of develop any clue in helpful.

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function()
         {
         $("#login").click(function(){
         var nombre=$("#nombre").val();
         var pass=$("#pass").val();

         var dataString= "nombre="+nombre+"&pass="+pass+"&login=true";
         if($.trim(nombre).length>0 & $.trim(pass).length>0){
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url:"https://crm.inter-web.es/app/json.php",
                 data: dataString,
                 crossDomain: true,
                 cache: false,
                 beforeSend: function(){ $("#login").val('Conectando...');
            },
            success: function(data){    
                return data;
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ alert(errorThrown);}
         });


            var url="https://crm.inter-web.es/app/json.php";
            $.getJSON(url, function(track){
                     console.log(track);
                     $(".list").append("<li>Nombre "+track['nombre']+"</li>");
                     $(".list").append("<li>Pass "+track['pass']+"</li>");
                });
         }return false;

         });
         });
 </script>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
//server code
include "db.php";
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $q=mysqli_query($con,"select nombre, pass from usuarios where nombre='".$_POST['nombre']."'");
    $datos=mysqli_fetch_all($q, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $num=mysqli_num_rows($q);

    $json=json_encode($datos);

    echo $json;
}else{
    $q=mysqli_query($con,"select * from clientes where id_cliente='62' ");
    $datos=mysqli_fetch_array($q, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $num=mysqli_num_rows($q);
    // var_dump($datos);
    // for ($i=0; $i < $num ; $i++) { 
    //      echo $datos[$i][0]."<br>";
    // }
    $json=json_encode($datos);
    // mkdir("./json/");
    // $fp=fopen("json/json.json", "w+");
    // fwrite($fp,$json);
    echo $json;
}


?>
```

Comment: `"nombre="+nombre+"&pass="+pass+"login=true"`. You're missing an & in there, aren't you?

Comment: Yes I do, totally my bad. Changing it same result, also tried with json in stead of string.

Comment: I might try 1) just making an object instead of a string `{"nombre": nombre, "pass":pass, "login": true}` then 2) On the PHP page do `print_r($_POST);` at the top so you can see what is happening, and finally 3) In the success in the ajax do `console.log(data);` before you return. Then you can see in your JS console what is coming back from the PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I did this with GET in stead of POST, my first code was redundant, I did 2 request to the server:

```
 $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url:"https://crm.inter-web.es/app/json.php",
             data: dataString,
             crossDomain: true,
             cache: false,
             beforeSend: function(){ $("#login").val('Conectando...');
        },
        success: function(data){    
            return data;
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ alert(errorThrown);}
     });
```

AND:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(track){
                 console.log(track);
                 $(".list").append("<li>Nombre "+track['nombre']+"</li>");
                 $(".list").append("<li>Pass "+track['pass']+"</li>");
            });
```

I modify the url with the GET parameters in the second way ("https://url?name=name&pass=pass") and it Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Instead trying to format a "dataString"... I suggest you to use an object:

```
dataObject = {
  nombre: $("#nombre").val(),
  pass: $("#pass").val(),
  login: true,
}
```

And in the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url:"https://crm.inter-web.es/app/json.php",
   data: dataObject,
   // ...
   success: function(data){    
            // return data;  // That line does nothing.
            console.log(data);
        },
```

Comment: I have tried bouth ways, but $_POST is empty again.

Comment: Ok I edited... In the `success` callback, the `return data;` does nothing. Try to console.log the json that is supposed to be returned.